# Python method parameter list

Tags: python

in a method definition why would someone set the formal parameter `amount` equal to the constant `PERMANENCE_INC` in the formal parameter list?

```
def increasePermanence(self, amount=PERMANENCE_INC): 
    """ Increases the permanence of this synapse. """ 
    self.permanence = min(1.0, self.permanence+amount)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That gives default value for the parameter in case it is not provided when the function is called.

For example, to increase permanence by default value, you would call:

```
obj.increasePermanence()
```

Answer (score 0):

This form makes `amount` an optional argument with a default value of `PERMANENCE_INC`.